# Can an Indian Qatari resident apply for a Japanese tourist visa with no income tax return and only bank statement?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm an Indian citizen, and I work as a driver in Qatar. I have been a fan of anime and kamen rider since childhood. I want to travel to Japan on a tourist visa.

I have only saved 3 lakhs rupees (USD 4000/JPY 440,000) in my savings account. Is it sufficient to prove this with my bank statement? I have no income tax return. Can someone explain how to apply for a tourist visa without one?

Comment: Are you a Qatari citizen?

Comment: How is that that you have been working as a driver but never filed an income tax return?

Comment: The rupee isn't the currency of Qatar. If your nationality isn't Qatari, and you have no proof of earnings, how is Qatar relevant?

Comment: Be aware that Japan is unlikely to reopen for tourism within the next 12 months.

Comment: Everyone listen, I m indian. I work as driver in qatar for 2 year.i have saving money since 1.5 year for japan.i have no itr.only I have bank statement to show...how can I get itr(income tax return) where I worked as a driver for someone?...right now situation is not possible but after covid I will visit to japan at any cost....so please tell me can I apply to tourist visa with no itr???

Answer (score 3):

Here is [the page from the Japanese embassy in Qatar telling you how to apply for a tourist visa.](https://www.qa.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/consular.html) Clicking on the "Foreign resident tourist staying in a hotel"<sup>1</sup> link will give you the requirements for a someone who is not a Qatar citizen applying from Qatar.

You need to provide:

1. ORIGINAL Passport (more than 3 months validity)
2. 1 Passport Copy (the pages of status items)
3. Visa Application Form
4. Photo
5. ORIGINAL Covering Letter from Employer in Qatar or Employee Certificate
6. Hotel Reservation (for the period of stay)
7. 1 Copy of Flight booking(entire trip)
8. 1 Copy of Qatar ID. Card
9. Schedule of stay in Japan
10. **Bank Statement for the last 6 months**
11. Copy of the previous Visa (Japan, America, Schengen etc.) if you have any

There is no mention of an income tax return.

There is also no mention of a minimum amount of money, as costs for trips vary according to your length of stay and your itinerary. You will need to demonstrate not just that you have a certain amount of money in your account, but that your earnings and spendings are such that it makes financial sense for you to take an expensive vacation.

**Notes**

1. That means someone who is a resident of Qatar but not a Qatar citizen, and will be visiting Japan for tourist purposes and staying in a hotel or similar accommodation, not staying with friends or relatives.

Comment: Dj clayworth I m from india not qatar citizen.i work as a driver in qatar.i m sorry for the mistake I haven't mentioned my nationality india...

Comment: You said that. The link tells you how to apply as a "foreign resident" (meaning not a Qatar citizen).

Comment: DJ CLAYWORTH but I see on requirement list that I need to have qatari id card

Comment: All legal residents of Qatar are required to have an ID card, also called a residence permit card.

Comment: Note that the employer letter needs to include the applicant's salary. Not an ITR, but they do want some proof of income.

Answer (score 1):

this is absolutely depending on what country are comming from and the "relationship" between japan and this country..

as an example,
here are the required docs for people in India:

[image]

BUT if you are in Mexico, the story gets harder:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to this instead of a copy? And can you link to the data for Qatar rather than India?

Comment: This answer is wrong in referring to "where the traveler is coming from."  The document cited lists documents required not according to where the traveler is coming from, but instead by reference to the applicant's nationality. India is not listed as an exception, so the requirements listed apply to Indian citizens like the OP.